# How to remove back button in ionic header only in one page

Tags: ionic-framework

I want to load a new view when a certain button is pressed. The view that loads should not show a back button to the previous page.

Back Button code:

```
<ion-nav-bar class="bar bar-header ionBarM " align-title="left">
        <ion-nav-title >
        <a ui-sref="app.feed"  ng-click="getEList()" > BACK<i class="pull-left ion-chevron-left"></i></a>  
        </ion-nav-title>
```

[image: what I actually want]

Comment: if the answers works for you, do you mind marking the answer accepted so it doesn't show up as a question that still needs an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On your `<ion-view>` add the hide-back-button attribute: `<ion-view hide-back-button="true">`

The functionality is clearly explained in the official documentation for ion-view: http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionView/

Comment: only true for ionic v1. no longer true for latest versions of ionic

Answer (score 1):

For latest Ionic versions try using

```
<ion-navbar hideBackButton >
```

This should work.